# How to use facebook's REST API call "LiveMessage.Send"

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

This might be a "possible" duplicate (I've read a few answers on here and none caught my eye :/) in which case I apologize! However I've been banging my head for 3 days now trying to get this right!

I have got a normal Canvas app setup (because FBML is being deprecated). All I want to do is as soon as the user "allows" access to my application a chat message must appear in his browser.

I've [read the API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/liveMessage.send/) about 100 times trying to see what I'm doing wrong or if this is even possible. Some people have said this works, others have said that the method needs an event hook that can only be create when initialing the "LiveMessage" object in FBJS.

Does anybody know if there is a way to do this, or if this is even possible? And if not what alternatives are there?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To clarify: is your program not catching the hint that it's been allowed to send the message, or is it just that the API call isn't working?

Comment: Hey, the API call is working fine (I even tested it in facebook's sandbox environment) It just never pops up :/

Answer (score 0):

LiveMessage is only available on FBML canvas pages, so you won't be able to use it in graph api (iframe apps).

Comment: No alternative available right now for this. I checked the Graph API JS SDK nothing found.

Comment: what about xmpp login permissions? that is used to connect to chat.facebook.com is it not? Can Inot then send a message to myself?

Comment: That was different thing you have to do a lot for fb chat. I have not checked it yet but Its something different and yes it can send message to user. I am not sure though

Comment: I'm sorry mani but in my question i clearly asked for alternatives. I can't give 100 rep away for a simple "no the API doesn't support it"